# Set Wordpress users' default display name to 'firstname + lastname' through functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find a solutions for displaying my users' display name in this format: "firstname lastname". By default, wordpress displays only the firstname for all of my users.

I've tried several codes found on internet but most of them are depreciated and no longer functional due to latest wordpress updates.

```
function change_display_name( $user_id ) {
$info = get_userdata( $user_id );
$args = array(
‘ID’ => $user_id,
‘display_name’ => $info->first_name . ‘ ‘ . $info->last_name
);
wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action(‘user_register’,’change_display_name’);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the get_userdata() function to get_user_meta()

```
function change_display_name( $user_id ) {

$key_first = 'first_name';
$key_last = 'last_name';
$single = true;
$user_first = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key_first, $single );
$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key_last, $single );     


$args = array(
‘ID’ => $user_id,
‘display_name’ => $user_first . ‘ ‘ . $user_last
);
wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action(‘user_register’,’change_display_name’)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue above with the following code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$howdy = sprintf( __( 'Darling %s' ), '<span class="display-name">' .$current_user->first_name. ''. $current_user->last_name . '</span>' );

echo $howdy;
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. It doesn't seem to be working for me either. It just displays 'Darling' in the header. That's all.

Comment: I think It's good to recheck your user's first name and last name. They might be empty. So you must write your name on Editing UserPage.